# If $(M_t)$ is a Martingale, why considering $\int_0^t X_s^2d\left<M\right>_s$ instead of $\int_0^t X_s^2ds$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $(M_t)$ a martingale. In the book of Karatzas and Shreve (Brownian motion and stochastic calculs), they often consider the integral $$I_t=\int_0^t X_s^2 d \left<M\right>_s,$$
where $(\left<M\right>_s)$ is s.t. $(M_s^2-\left<M\right>_s)$ is a Martingale. I can imagine that my question can be not so precise, but in what $I_s$ is interesting ? Why considering $I_t$ rather than $\int_0^t X_s^2d s$ is interesting ?

---

Well, my question also work for : why considering $$\int_0^t X_s d \left<M\right>_s\quad \text{instead of }\int_0^t X_s d s \ \ ?$$

Comment: $\int_0^t X_s \ \mathsf d\langle M\rangle_s$ is a stochastic integral. $\int_0^t X_s\ \mathsf ds$ is a time integral. Two completely different things.

Comment: The integral $I_t$ is interesting because it it the compensator of $Y_t := \int_0^t X_s \, dM_s$, e.g. it allows you to compute the expectation of $Y_t^2$.

Comment: @saz: What do you mean by compensator ? So except to compute $\mathbb E[Y_t^2]$ it's not interesting ?

Comment: @Math1000: For me $\int_0^t X_s d\left<M\right>_s$ is a Stiljes integral and not a Stochastic integral (since $t\mapsto \left<M\right>_t$ has bounded variation and is not a martingale).

Comment: @Walace Well, it was just an example... you can use the compensator also for other things. (By compensator I mean the object which you denote by $\langle \cdot \rangle$... so I'm saying that $\langle Y \rangle_t = I_t$ for the process $Y$ defined in my previous comment.)